# Android: Zxing barcode lib parse a string to BarcodeFormat

Tags: android, zxing

I am using zxing barcode lib for decoding barcodes in my application. I successfully gets the ISBN from the barcode on activityresult.  However i also needs to get the barcode type so i added another parameter that is **getBarcodeFormat()** in the return intent as extras. an excerpt of the code is below

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("ISBN", rawResult.getText());
        intent.putExtra("BarCodeType",rawResult.getBarcodeFormat());
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
```

On my actual activity i gets the barcodeformat in string format but i need it to parse into BarcodeFormat object since i need to again covert the isbn to barcode using

`writer.encode(contentsToEncode, format, img_width, img_height, hints);`

method which accepts the BarcodeFormat object instead of string format. I couldn't find any method in BarcodeFormat documentation. If anyone has the solution to it, kindly share. I'll be really thankful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Following method worked for me,

```
BarcodeFormat format=BarcodeFormat.valueOf(BarCodeType);
```

Previously i used the wrong string so was getting the exception.